# How to get input within response in gradio

Tags: gradio, gradio-chatinterface

So I am working on getting input with response function in gradio. In python, we have input() where it would pause execution until user provides input, I require similar functionality in gradio in highlighted part of image.

Example code:

[image]

Is there a way to do so?